# Trigger to check foreign key not working in PLSQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Here are my 2 `tables` that I am using

```
create table EMPLOYEE (
                    Eid number(5) primary key,
                    Ename char(30),
                    Designation char(30));

create table Attendance (
                        Eid number(5) references EMPLOYEE(Eid),
                        tdate date,
                        attendance char(2) check(attendance in('P','A')));
```

Here is the `Procedure` I am using to take attendance

```
create or replace PROCEDURE take_attendance(
                                            id IN number,
                                            attendance IN char) IS
begin 
    insert into ATTENDANCE Values(id, sysdate, attendance);
end;
```

Here is the `Trigger` I am using

```
create or replace TRIGGER to_take_attendance
before insert or update of eid on ATTENDANCE
for each row
declare
    CURSOR c(n number) is select * from EMPLOYEE where eid = :new.eid;
    e c%rowtype;
    invalid_id EXCEPTION;
begin
open c(:new.eid);
    fetch c into e;
    if c%NOTFOUND then
        raise invalid_id;
    else
        NULL;
    end if;

EXCEPTION   
when invalid_id then
    close c;
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Invalid ID');

close c;
end;
```

Here are the `Errors` I am getting

```
begin
*
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-20001: Invalid ID 
ORA-06512: at "101503028.TO_TAKE_ATTENDANCE", line 17 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '101503028.TO_TAKE_ATTENDANCE' 
ORA-06512: at "101503028.TAKE_ATTENDANCE", line 5 
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I am not sure why I am getting those errors. I am new to PL/SQL is my question my be very stupid.

Thanks!

EDIT - Removed the others in exception.

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of the trigger is here. The database system already enforces the validity of foreign key values without needing you to define a trigger.

Comment: I am supposed to implement a trigger for the same purpose.

Comment: @lord_ozb As an aside, get rid of that when others clause - you are currently masking every single error as an invalid id. That isn't going to help you when someone comes to you and says "I'm getting 'invalid id' when I insert a row for an id that exists!". However, as Damien says, the foreign key already enforces the rule that the employee eid already exists. Why are you supposed to implement a trigger? Is this a homework question, or is it some sort of business requirement? If you're trying to handle the error nicely, then it would be better to do it in the code that calls the insert.

Comment: @Boneist Thanks. 
I have dropped away the idea or triggers and now using Exception Handling.

Comment: @lord_ozb that'd be the best way to handle it, IMHO. Just don't assume every error is going to be an invalid id; give yourself some hope of being able to debug issues by not masking errors unnecessarily! You'll thank yourself later, I promise *{:-)

Comment: For extra marks, explain why you could not safely and reliably use such a trigger instead of a foreign key constraint in a real system.

Comment: @TonyAndrews I'm somewhat heartened by the fact the OP was using a fkey already, rather than trying to rely solely on the trigger to handle the referential integrity! *{:-)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting errors because your trigger works as expected.
You are trying to insert to ATTENDANCE, ID that does not exist in EMPLOYEE.

Exception defined in your code:
raise_application_error(**-20001**,'**Invalid ID**');

Error received:
ORA-**20001**: **Invalid ID**

Comment: But what about this? `ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '101503028.TO_TAKE_ATTENDANCE`

Comment: @lord_ozb - ignore it. Just a chain of exceptions.

Comment: [ORA-04088](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/ORA-02140.htm#GUID-008ABD32-275E-467A-AE6B-04976F2A8462__GUID-D9B490A8-8BB3-40BE-BD8C-F98175A670E1) is just the generic message for a trigger failure.